# PCRE Regex Matching Patterns until next pattern is found

Tags: regex, pcre

I'm struggling to find a solution to this regex which appears to be fairly straight forward.  I need to match a pattern that precedes another matching pattern.

I need to capture the "Mean:" that follows "Keberos-wsfed" in the following:

```
Kerberos:
  Historical:
   Between 26 and 50 milliseconds: 10262
   Between 50 and 100 milliseconds: 658
   Between 101 and 200 milliseconds: 9406
   Between 201 and 500 milliseconds: 6046
   Between 501 milliseconds and 1 second: 1646
   Between 1 and 5 seconds: 1399
   Between 6 and 10 seconds: 13
   Between 11 and 30 seconds: 34
   Between 31 seconds and 1 minute: 7
   Between 1 minute and 2 minutes: 1
   Mean: 268, Mode: 36, Median: 123
   Total: 29472
 Kerberos-wsfed:
  Historical:
   Between 26 and 50 milliseconds: 3151
   Between 50 and 100 milliseconds: 129
   Between 101 and 200 milliseconds: 650
   Between 201 and 500 milliseconds: 411
   Between 501 milliseconds and 1 second: 171
   Between 1 and 5 seconds: 119
   Between 6 and 10 seconds: 4
   Between 11 and 30 seconds: 6
   Between 1 minute and 2 minutes: 1
   Mean: 176, Mode: 33, Median: 37
   Total: 4642
```

I can match (?:Kerberos-wsfed:), I can match Mean: but I must find the value of Mean after Kerberos-wsfed but having difficulty.  Thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the regex

```
Kerberos-wsfed[\s\S]*?Mean: *(\d+)
```

The mean value is contained in the capturing group 1, that is `$1` or `\1` depending on your programming language.

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/2jDmiY/1).

Comment: horcrux, working exactly as I need it to.  Thanks for putting it all together!

Comment: @mrmiz, don't forget to select best answer please.

Comment: `[\s\S]*?` is a hack you'd use in JavaScript because it lacks support for the `s` flag, you don't have to use it in PCRE. Juste use `(?s:.*?)` instead if you can't apply `s` to the whole pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Using capturing group:

```
Kerberos-wsfed:[\s\S]*Mean:\s(\d+)
```

- `Kerberos-wsfed:` matches the literal as-is
- `[\s\S]*` allows any number of characters between (including line delimitters)
- `Mean:\s` matches the literal `Mean` followed by a space `\s`
- Finally `(\d+)` which is wrapped in the first capturing group captures the value you are looking for. It essentially allows any number of digits

[Regex 101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/PXeZMe/1/)

The value that you are looking for (`176`) will be in the first capturing group which is `$1` or the first one based on your language. For instance, in PHP:

```
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

echo $matches[0][1];
// Output: 176
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use that regular expresion: `#Kerberos-wsfed:.+?Mean:\s+(\d+)#s`

You can use just space or `\s` instead of `\s+` if you're shure in file format.

Value `176` will be at group 1 of matched elements

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/gwkUPJ/1

Comment: You should have specified that this regex works only in "single line" mode.